# an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format exception going away with VS installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dllimport

I've designed a C# Windows appln which also calls internally some functions [imported from C++ DLL through DllImport()]

My C++ code is built as .DLL in Win32 platform whereas my C# is built as "Any CPU" platform.

When I run the .EXE (C#) in my test machine, I face an error as

> an attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
>   exception from hresult 0x8007000B

However, this error is not faced if I install VSS 2010 in my machine and then run the EXE.

**1) Reason for this error?
2) why is the error not observed when VSS is installed?**

I've used Win7 OS(64bit) to build the .EXE (C#) in **AnyCPU** platform which in turn depends on a DLL (C++ Dll imported in C# using DllImport) built in **Win32**

Comment: I would guess that it is a bitness mismatch error -- your .dll is 32-bit and your .exe is 64-bit or the other way around. VS installs a whole bunch of stuff, although I have no idea how exactly that would resolve your problem.

Comment: Please update your question to include the OS, .dll bitness and .exe bitness. Also, check your build settings and force the .Net part to match the bitness of your .dll.

Comment: Ive checked all my settings and have updated above. pl let know:

Comment: What about the machine you're running it on? Note that Win32 is just the name of the low-level Windows API and that there is no Win64, although a Win32 application can be compiled to a 64-bit .exe.

Answer (score 11):

This is almost always because you are calling 32bit code from 64bit dll/exe,etc or a 64bit dll from a 32bit dll.  What happens if you build the c# for x86?  It will still run on 64bit.

Comment: I'm still wondering because the test machine is 32bit and how the C++ dll is generated as 64bit one when I've selected Win32 in platform.

when I use x86 (instead of Any CPU), this problem is solved. what's the issue in detail here?

Comment: Any CPU means that the framework will figure out whether to run as 64 or 32 bit on application start.  I would have expected the test machine to be 64 and thus not being able to call the 32bit c++ dll at runtime.

Comment: Dll is built as Win32 and EXE is built as Any CPU platform (in VSS) on a x86bit machine where VS is installed. Now, Test machine has x86 version of OS where this application is being run. From where, 64bit is pitching in as everything is x86.

Comment: I encountered the same problem which the C#  main program is in release x86 mode and try to load a C++ DLL. When I selected x86  instead of Any CPU in project property page, the problem disappeared.